# Which Myanmar unicode version do I have to choose?

Tags: unicode, fonts, version

It is quite obvious that people stop using Zawgyi font and moving to Unicode. So I made my mind to start giving a try to Unicode. Since I've never installed Unicode before , I start googling and found a [site](http://www.myanmarlanguage.org/unicode/myanmar-fonts-which-follow-unicode-rules) . To my surprise, there is more than 1 Unicode font . If you have experience using Unicode before, please suggest which version is most suitable to use.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a modern operating system, Unicode is already "installed" and any font you have supports it.

Just pick a font you like that supports the characters you need. A simple "[language/script] font" search query in Google should be able to give you a nice list of fonts available to download.